# Creating Multi Level Quick Launch Navigation

Tags: 2010, 2013, navigation

I have a requirement to create multi level left navigation in SP 2013. I have been able to acheive the same with the help of Term Store. But since I have many subsites (all with 3-5 levels of navigation), crowding the Termstore with too many terms has not been recommended.

Can someone suggest what could be the alternate approach / some pointers for the same!!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

How much is too much?  TermStore supports 1 mil. items with 30K per term set (2k for managed navigation).  I assume it's the depth that is your problem, as the TermStore will only go 7 levels.

If that is the case (the depth) - I highly recommend you re-visit your navigation hierarchy. Going more than 3 levels deep becomes a usability nightmare.

You can switch from Managed navigation back to static and just populate per site, or you can create a custom navigation provider and replace the quick launch on your page.  You then use a custom sitemap provider that points at your data source. That takes a bit more work though of course.

MSDN Refrence for custom navigation:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms432695%28v=office.14%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the response. BTW, I will have 200+ sub sites, all with different navigation with maximum level being 5. The problem is having these many number of termsets. I don't want to over populate the TermStore.

Comment: You can have up to 1000 term sets in your term store, so you are still well under your limit.